# Add span in PHP Code in last div

Tags: php, html, css

> **Add Span in php**
>   **last div don't work :(**

**How to Add span in php code **

```
 echo"
<tr>
        <td>$id</td>
        <td>$name</td>
        <td>$lastname</td>
        <td>$email</td>
        <td>$login</td>
        <td>$password</td>
        <td class="td-actions">
                                                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="logout.php">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>enter code here

 </tr>";
```

Comment: You're opening your PHP string with double quotes and then closing it too early because you're also using double quotes to wrap HTML attributes, Try mixing them. I will post an example as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `echo` is using `"` to indicate where the text begins and ends, you'll need to escape the `"` within the text itself with a `\`:

```
echo "
<tr>
    <td>$id</td>
    <td>$name</td>
    <td>$lastname</td>
    <td>$email</td>
    <td>$login</td>
    <td>$password</td>
    <td class=\"td-actions\">
        <a class=\"btn btn-default btn-xs\" href=\"logout.php\">
            <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span> Edit
        </a>
    </td>enter code here
</tr>";
```